# ASP NET Core SQL Server Docker-Compose entry point bash script show errors on logs

Tags: bash, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I'm dockerizing an app but the entry point script doesn't work. The app couldn't perform CRUD actions and shows the "failed logging in with sa" error. I checked out the database because I suspect that the database didn't get created and yes, it didn't. So I thought the problem has to be the entry point script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

until dotnet database update; do
echo "SQL Server is starting up"
sleep 1
done

echo "SQL Server is up - executing command"
dotnet database update
```

This script doesn't stop the app from building but it shows this in the log:

```
./Setup.sh: 1: ./Setup.sh: #!/bin/bash
not found
./Setup.sh: 2: ./Setup.sh: 
not found
./Setup.sh: 3: set: Illegal option -
```

Here's the the docker file that's supposed to run the script above (named Migrations.Dockerfile):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Project/Project.csproj", "Project/"]
COPY Setup.sh Project/Setup.sh

RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef

RUN dotnet restore "./Project/Project.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Project"

RUN /root/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef migrations add InitialMigrations

RUN chmod +x ./Setup.sh
CMD /bin/sh ./Setup.sh
```

And here's the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  project:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}project
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Project/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9080:80"
    depends_on: 
      - migrations
      - db
  db:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "W0WV3RYSTRONGPASSWORD!"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
        - "14331:1433"
    depends_on: 
        - migrations
  migrations:
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: Migrations.Dockerfile
```

Comment: Looks like your shell doesn't understand the commands in the script. You've not posted enough of your files for me to make a guess as to why that might be.

Comment: @Hans Hi. Thanks for checking it out. I've edited the question to add more information